# How to pass property as parameter in C#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class

```
class Item
{
    public int A {get; set}
    public int B {get; set}
    public int C {get; set}
}
```

I have a method `parseData(List<Item> items, <reference to property>)` which should iterate through `items` and get only required property from each item. What is the most effective way to do it in C#. Should I use `Expression` for this (but I cannot figure out how to do it)?

Comment: I think that going with expressions is a bit of an overkill, can you provide the context of the bigger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It sounds like you're essentially talking about `Select`, i.e. `var vals = list.Select(x => x.A);` - can you clarify the context more? `Select` works very much like the `Func<TSource, TValue>` in Sweeper's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a property, you could probably use a `Func<Item, T>`:

```
// I don't know what this method returns so I used "void".
public void ParseData<T>(List<Item> items, Func<Item, T> propertySelector) {
    // as an example, here's how to get the property of the first item in the list
    var firstItemsProperty = propertySelector(items.First());
    ...
}
```

You can call this method by passing a lambda expression:

```
ParseData(itemList, x => x.Property1) // "Property1" is a property declared in "Item"
```

Comment: I was about to post pretty much the same thing, but I got to thinking what use T is inside ParseData. You wouldn't be able to do anything useful with firstItemsProperty because you don't know what type it will be. The OP may just need Func<Item, int> in their example, or perhaps some where constraint to ensure T supports some interface, or a third Action<T> parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Some Reflection if you will

```
public void ParseData(List<Item> items, String PropertyName)
{
    foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        var prop = typeof(Item).GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(item, null);            
    }
}
```